# Substr from isset GET url

Tags: php, image, url, web, get

I googled many time but didn't see any solution.
Now my site are almost done,but just one more issue
I don't how to write the code about getting the url from the current url
for example:http://abc.com/123.php?url=http://xyz.com/169.jpg
how can I get the http://xyz.com/169.jpg and echo that?
I tried using substr or preg_match but didn't work..
please help!!

Comment: Your question is not really clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need something like this.

```
 $url = $_GET['url'];
```

Comment: now i have a var named $url for testing the script,it work perfect,but i don't understand how to use $_GET function to find the url of url

Comment: $_GET is an associative array, not a function.

Answer (score 0):

Check the manual page for the **HTTP** variable [here](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

good luck!

Comment: not a http request,i just want to crop the url from current url,thanks for the answer:)

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
  $url = isset($_GET['url']) ? urldecode($_GET['url']) : null ;
```